# Is it okay to use request code used in intent's startActivityForResult() as regular variable?

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList<String>` in the `MainActivity`. I would like to send one of the item in list to `EditItemActivity`. I'm using `intent.putExtra()` fow sending the String object. I was also going to send the index as an integer object too. But I realized I could probably use the "request code" variable as my index for `ArrayList<String>`.

Code example shown in the [Android developer's document](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#StartActivity) uses `static final int REQUEST_CODE`. Now, I'm not sure if changing (what would normally be a ) static final to a regular variable is a good practice. I would like to get some insight from more experienced developer in case I'm not realizing something important.

Here in my code, I set `request_code = pos`. It feels like a hack. Is this conventional way of using request code?

```java
// MainActivity.java

private int request_code;
ArrayList<String> items;
ListView listView;

...    

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditItemActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("text", items.get(pos));
            request_code = pos;
            startActivityForResult(i, request_code);
    }
});

...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == request_code){
        String newText = data.getExtras().getString("newText");
        items.set(request_code, newText);
        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

```java
// EditItemActivity.java

public void onSaveItem(View v) {
    String newText = editText.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("newText", newText);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `static final int` for your request codes gives you the opportunity to evaluate them in `onActivityResult()`, for example using switch-case-blocks. By choosing meaningful variable names, you can make your code more readable, which is always a good thing.

Using arbitrary request code values won't do harm technically. Your `Activity` usually will not be able to have two such requests running simultaneously, so I suppose you're on the safe side there. But what do you actually gain by this approach? If you want to compare the incoming request code to anything, you'll have to keep this variable int value in your `Activity`'s memory. This means saving the value in `onSaveInstanceState()` and retrieving it again in `onRestoreInstanceState()` so you still can access it after a configuration change. Seems to be a lot of trouble and not really anything on the plus side.

That's why I 'd use `static final int` request codes.

Comment: "But what do you actually gain by this approach?" I don't have to send extra (redundant) information in intent's putExtra. I'm using the ArrayList's index as a request code since it also happens to be unique"

Comment: @Leo Kim - Well... no. I think I don't get your point, sorry. As far as I can see, you don't access the request-code-position in the other Activity (I'm not even sure you can do it)

Comment: You sort of got it :) You are right, I'm not using it in my EditItemActivity. But upon updating the String object, I send it back to the MainActivity. MainActivity can read the update but doesn't know which of the item in ArrayList got updated. So I need to keep track of the index. I could either 1) send index in the indent or 2) use save index as request code and retrieve index upon data return.

Comment: Well, you seem to store the position in the first Activity in order to compare it to the incoming request code. If you would do without that and trust your request code blindly, then, ok, I think you can do it this way and skip the whole save-my-variable-across-config-change-business

Comment: It may happen that the EditItemActivity is interrupted (the famous incoming call...) and the users return much later to finish what they started. In this case, your first Activity will get the result but you should also make sure somehow that all the adapters/ Views etc. are set up and running before calling notifyDatasetChanged() The position might not be enough to identify the item if the data changed (have to be reloaded from somewhere)

Comment: I would not worry about the extra bytes, but I read somewhere that one should not send sensitive information via startActivity(). All in all, I think you can do it your way, but be aware that some people may not understand or like the pattern (code is less easy to maintain). Alternatively, you can store the position/ id/ ... in SharedPreferences

Comment: That pretty much got all my questions answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is important to understand what the request code is actually doing. In your onActivityResult method, request code is generally used to determine what activity actually produced a result. This is useful especially when you may have opened different activities that may produce different types of results. When its only one activity that might produce a result it doesn't really matter what that code is so long as you give one. In this case you could just feed the startActivityForResult method any old number without ever declaring a variable and everything would really be fine.

Typically the request code is a static final variable because the developer knows they might have more than one kind of activity with more than one kind of result, and this way they have an easy way to make sure all the possible request codes are unique and the variable name can be used to identify what type of result you are getting in a switch state or similar. Since this is a likely situation, it is pretty standard to do it this way and that is why Android Developers guide suggests it.

It is also generally helpful and pretty standard practice to store any kind of indicator code like a request code (or any label like an unchanging string) as a static final variable for a couple reasons. First, any time you make modifications to your code or use it in another code block somewhere else, or compare a variable to your code, you can simply use that static final variable and know you have not made a mistake and put in the wrong code from your memory. If you want to add another type of code you would do it in the same manner, and you would write the variable in the same part of the file and be able to easily confirm you don't accidentally make the codes the same. By indicator code I do not mean like the index of a list, but a code for one of only a few options that do not change. (Like a code for EditItem and a different one for NewItem).

To your situation, basically you aren't hurting anything doing it like you are doing, but yes some developers might find it a little bit weird. To more of a software engineering perspective, you are using request code for something other than its intended purpose, and another developer that reads your code might not instantly know why you are doing that. Then again, some might find it a little clever. Either way, there's nothing particularly wrong with it. One thing if you do it like that you don't need the private variable request_code at all. Below I made a couple changes to clean it up just a bit, and make it more obvious exactly how you are choosing to use the code.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditItemActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("text", items.get(pos));
            startActivityForResult(i, pos);
    }
});


   ...


   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //No need to compare requestCode with anything, as it always defines the index, not the type of result
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String newText = data.getExtras().getString("newText");
        items.set(requestCode, newText);
        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I would still need to assign `request_code=pos` if I want to update the correct index using this method.

Comment: I'm not sure why? request_code does not change in between when you send the activity for result and when the result comes back, and with my code will always be the selected item. When it comes back as requestCode it will be the same value as pos

Comment: Dang it. I misread something from your code. Yes this would indeed work.